# easypaginate error, it doesn´t work

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

When im trying implement easypaginate in my code, firebug alerts me with this error: 
"ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
[Parar en este error]

slice.call( docElem.childNodes, 0 )[0].nodeType;"

HTML:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>CURSOS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="treeview.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="easypaginate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="treeview.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>



  </head>

  <body>
        <div id="JQTreeview">
        </div>
        <ul id ="output">
            This is the default output
        </ul>
        <div class="pages"></div>
        <input type='button' id='corregir' value='Corregir' />
        <input type='button' id='corregir1' value='Corregir' />

  </body>
```

JS:

```
function muestraArray(x){
    $("#output").text("");  
    $("#output").easyPaginate({step:2});


    var i=0;
    // se conocen el numero de propiedades y el nombre de cada objeto
    for(p in preguntas){ //Cada elemento p de cada preguntas
        test = preguntas[p]; //test contiene las claves
        //$("#output").append("<h3>" + petPos + "</h3>");
            $("#output").append('<div id="preg'+i+'"><br><h3>'+test.pregunta + "</h3><br>");    //tes.pregunta, test.resp1, ... contiene los valores    
            //$("#output").append(pet["nombre"] + "<br>");  
            $("#output").append('<input type="radio" name="resp'+i+'" value="'+test.resp1+'">'+test.resp1 + '<span class="'+test.resp1+'"></span><br>');
            $("#output").append('<input type="radio" name="resp'+i+'" value="'+test.resp2+'">'+test.resp2 + '<span class="'+test.resp2+'"></span><br>');
            $("#output").append('<input type="radio" name="resp'+i+'" value="'+test.resp3+'">'+test.resp3 + '<span class="'+test.resp3+'"></span><br></li>');
            i++;
    }// end for

    if(x==1){
    $(init);
    }
    if(x==2){
    $(init2);
    }
    if(x==3){
    $(init3);
    }
    if(x==4){
    $(init4);


    }
} // end processResults
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the order of loading your script files,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="easypaginate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="easypaginate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just modified, now firebug alerts: TypeError: $(...).easyPaginate is not a function

$("#output").easyPaginate({step:2});

Comment: @jarab where & how are you calling muestraArray() function..?

Comment: Here you can check: http://jsfiddle.net/gnJze/
Only the js, where muestraArray() is called